# How can I display all the objects of array from fetch in div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

How do I save my array of objects in a proper way? and then display them in html?
Console log can print the whole array but it does not work the same in html

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      quotes: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ quotes: data }));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.quotes.text);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.quotes[0].author}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Use map: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#embedding-map-in-jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map through the quotes in the JSX.

```js
return (
   <div>
     {this.state.quotes && this.state.quotes.map(quote => (
       <div>
         <h1>{quote.author}</h1>
         <p>{quote.content}</p>
       </div>
     ))}
   </div>
 );
```

Tell me if I misunderstood something or if it helps :)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to close the parenthesis :) Check out the edited answer.

Comment: what if I want to print both name and text, do I need to map twice?

Comment: No, you can just add another jsx tag check the edited answer

Comment: Great... it looks fantastic :)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```js
const quotes = this.state.quotes.map((quote) => {
      return (
          <div>
              <h1>{quote.author}</h1>
          </div>
      );
    });
```

Then use this *quotes* inside return of your main component like this:

```js
return(
    <div>{quotes}</div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {
   quotes : []
 };
}

  componentDidMount() {
  fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((data) => this.setState({ quotes: data }))
}

 render() {
 console.log(this.state.quotes.text)
 return (
  
   <div>
     {this.state.quotes ?
      {this.state.quotes.map(quotes.author=> (
        <h1>{author}</h1>
      ))}
     :
     <h1>{"Not loaded"}</h1>
     }
   </div>
 );
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Array.prototype.map` to generate jsx elements. in the render method:

```
render() {
    retrun(
    {this.state.quotes.map(quote => (
         <div>
              <h2>{qutoe.author}<h2>
         </div>
    ))}
   )
}
```